# How to wrap JSX elements in a single div when using .map() with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**What I want to do:**

Render a list of items as a component inside of another component

```
<div>
...
  <RenderBuildings buildings={this.props.buildingData} />
...
</div>
```

**What happens:**

I get this error:

```
Syntax Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag
```

What my code looks like:

```
const RenderBuildings = (props) => {
       return (
         props.buildings.allComps.map((building, index) => {
            let id = index + 1
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn style={{width: 12}}>{id}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{building.name}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{building.address}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{building.status}</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          )
  }
```

**What I suspect is happening:**

Seems pretty clear that the whole thing should be somehow be wrapped in a div, but I'm not sure how to make that work with a map function. How do you wrap the whole response in that?

Comment: You're not returning anything from the map

Comment: TableRow  must have the `key` prop

Comment: you can also use the `Fragment` component  https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below, `.map` requires a `return` statement when body is in curly braces.

```js
const RenderBuildings = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {props.buildings.allComps.map((building, index) => {
      let id = index + 1;
      return (
        <TableRow key={'row' + index}>
          <TableRowColumn style={{width: 12}}>{id}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{building.name}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{building.address}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{building.status}</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
      );
     });}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great! This absolutely works, which is weird because I thought I had tried this, but when I copy-pasted your code it worked. Looks like I had the right idea and it was just some weird sort of syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are building a table

```
   import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
   const RenderBuildings = (props) => {
   return (
     <Fragment>
      {
        props.buildings.allComps.map((building, index) => {
          let id = index + 1
          return (
             <TableRow key={id}>
               <TableRowColumn style={{width: 12}}>{id}</TableRowColumn>
               <TableRowColumn>{building.name}</TableRowColumn>
               <TableRowColumn>{building.address}</TableRowColumn>
               <TableRowColumn>{building.status}</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          )
        })
       }
   </Fragment >
  )
}
```

Comment: Fragments were introduced in react 16.2, so make sure you are using a current version of react if you want to use them. https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

Answer (score 1):

This is correct code for you..

```
const RenderBuildings = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {props.buildings.allComps.map((building, index) => {
      let id = index + 1;
      return (
        <TableRow key={'row' + index}>
          <TableRowColumn style={{width: 12}}>{id}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{building.name}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{building.address}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{building.status}</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
      );
     });}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you mention you try this but i think you forgot to add return in map funtion. Because I was also done similar mistake when i just start coding in es6.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve:

```js
const RenderBuildings = (props) => {
return (
 <div>
   props.buildings.allComps.map((building, index) => {
      let id = index + 1
        <TableRow key={id}>
          <TableRowColumn style={{width: 12}}>{id}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{building.name}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{building.address}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{building.status}</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
      )}
 </div>
)
```